# Not getting display in razor page in asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'm trying to create a razor page to create some users programmatically.  I'm doing something wrong at this point (obviously).
Inside of my pagemodel, I have the following:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

In my cshtml, I have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label asp-for="@Model.FirstName"></label></td>
        <td><input asp-for="@Model.FirstName" /> <span asp-validation-for="Model.FirstName" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would expect to get a label that says "First Name" and a textfield that has the value (in this specific use case, I would not expect a value).  Unfortunately, I am getting nothing.  Any help is appreciated.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><label></label></td>
    <td><input /> <span asp-validation-for="Model.FirstName" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `@Model` portion on the tag-helpers, you only need the property name:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label asp-for="FirstName"></label></td>
        <td><input asp-for="FirstName" /> <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmmm, without the @Model, I get this in my output:
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label asp-for="FirstName"></label></td>
            <td><input asp-for="FirstName" /> <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

Comment: I would think I want to get something like:
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="FirstName"></label></td>
            <td><input ID="FirstName" Name="FirstName" value="" /> <span <!-- and something that goes in here --> /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

As always, thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so the problem was that i forgot to add the tag helpers to the page.  problem solved.  thanks @McGuireV10 :-)